# Как воспроизвести ogg файл

Tags: c#, аудио, ogg

Использую для воспроизведения nuget NVorbis и NAudio. Но при создании VorbisWaveReader происходит ошибка:

```
Could not determine container type!
```

листинг

```
private static string demoStr = @"https://text-to-speech-demo.mybluemix.net/api/synthesize?text=Conscious+of+its+spiritual+and+moral+heritage%2C+the+Union+is+founded+on+the+indivisible%2C+universal+values+of+human+dignity%2C+freedom%2C+equality+and+solidarity%3B+it+is+based+on+the+principles+of+democracy+and+the+rule+of+law.+It+places+the+individual+at+the+heart+of+its+activities%2C+by+establishing+the+citizenship+of+the+Union+and+by+creating+an+area+of+freedom%2C+security+and+justice.&voice=en-US_AllisonVoice&download=true";
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         using (var wb = new WebClient())
         {
            var res =  wb.DownloadData(demoStr);
            File.WriteAllBytes("1.ogg", res);
            var response = wb.DownloadString(demoStr);
            var file = File.OpenRead("1.ogg");

            using (var vorbis = new NAudio.Vorbis.VorbisWaveReader("1.ogg"))
            using (var waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOut())
            {
               waveOut.Init(vorbis);
               waveOut.Play();
            }
         }
      }
```

В чем может быть ошибка или как еще можно воспроизвести ogg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал com библиотеку Windows Media Player

```
using WMPLib;
{    
... 
     WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
     wmp.URL = @"1.ogg";
     wmp.controls.play();
...
}
```

Comment: Только учтите, что WindowsMediaPlayer по умолчанию не может воспроизводить ogg-файлы. Нужны дополнительные кодеки.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov спасибо, учту. Видимо у меня они уже были